# Tensorflow ServingInputReceiver input shape error in client

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-estimator

I'm currently working with tensorflow Estimator API and have problems with the confusing serving options that are available. My confusion comes from the very undetailed tensorflow documentation.

This is my goal:
Use tensorflow-serving prediction_service_pb2 by sending a serialized proto message as string to the ServingInputReceiver function of my exported Estimator model. I expect the ServingInputReceiver function to receive the serialized proto string on the "input" tensor which then will deserialize it to the features "ink" (=varlength float array) and "shape" (=fixedlength int64).

**This is my (implementation of google quickdraw model) estimator Input function:**

```
def _parse_tfexample_fn(example_proto, mode):
    """Parse a single record which is expected to be a tensorflow.Example."""
    feature_to_type = {
        "ink": tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32),
        "shape": tf.FixedLenFeature([2], dtype=tf.int64)
    }
    if mode != tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        # The labels won't be available at inference time, so don't add them
        # to the list of feature_columns to be read.
        feature_to_type["class_index"] = tf.FixedLenFeature([1], dtype=tf.int64)

    parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_to_type)
    parsed_features["ink"] = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features["ink"])

    if mode != tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        labels = parsed_features["class_index"]
        return parsed_features, labels
    else:
        return parsed_features  # In prediction, we have no labels
```

**This is my Serving Input Function:**

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
"""An input receiver that expects a serialized tf.Example."""
feature_to_type = {"ink": tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.float32), "shape": tf.FixedLenFeature([2], dtype=tf.int64)}

serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string, shape=[None], name='input')

parsed_features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_to_type)
parsed_features["ink"] = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(parsed_features["ink"])

return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(parsed_features, serialized_tf_example)
```

**This is my client.py request:**

```
features = {}
features["ink"] = tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=np_ink.flatten()))
features["shape"] = tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=np_ink.shape))
f = tf.train.Features(feature=features)
data = tf.train.Example(features=f)
serialized=data.SerializeToString() # tensor to byte string
request.inputs['input'].ParseFromString(tf.contrib.util.make_tensor_proto(serialized, shape=[1], verify_shape=True))
```

**And this is the error I get after calling the Predict function in client.py**

```
grpc.framework.interfaces.face.face.AbortionError: AbortionError(code=StatusCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT, details="input tensor alias not found in signature: ink. Inputs expected to be in the set {input}.")
```

**I tried the following Servingfunctions:**
**ServingInputReceiver** and **build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn** give me the same grpc error. When I use **build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn** it wont even export my model. I tried to wrap my head around the documentation but it is very undetailed and I don't understand when to use which serving input function.